Multiline link hover animation and underline offset
I have this link animation. I want the link to be underlined by default, and then add an animated underline on hover (underline sliding in from left). This example is doing exactly what I'm looking for, but on hover the underlining is too close to the anchor text - probably because I'm switching from text-decoration to a background.
So, how can I move the hover background down to match the text-underline-offset? Adding background-position: left bottom -5px; to the hover won't work.


a {
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
   text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(#000, #000) left bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 1px;
  
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-size: 100% 1px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  /* background-position: left bottom -5px; */
}

body {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
<p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet picanha pork leberkas tail pig capicola. Fatback bacon rump biltong pastrami meatball cow. Meatloaf venison doner, flank swine pig beef bresaola corned beef capicola tri-tip bacon. Tri-tip rump ham short loin. Prosciutto porchetta corned beef rump. Pork chislic tri-tip short loin landjaeger andouille alcatra jerky sausage turkey. Chuck pastrami t-bone boudin doner pancetta pork chop flank pork shank spare ribs drumstick.</p>
<p>
<h3>Hover this link</h3>
  Andouille pork t-bone beef pig burgdoggen jowl. Shank short loin landjaeger rump alcatra pork belly jerky hamburger. <a href="">Pig cupim tongue meatball hamburger fatback flank prosciutto pork belly shank.</a>Chuck bresaola buffalo, short loin cow tongue tenderloin landjaeger beef cupim boudin shankle chislic t-bone. Sausage tenderloin hamburger leberkas kielbasa doner corned beef frankfurter tri-tip venison pastrami burgdoggen shankle. Kielbasa pancetta chicken strip steak. Cow bresaola biltong, boudin frankfurter filet mignon chislic andouille ham pork belly pastrami kevin.
</p>
<p>
  Biltong alcatra venison burgdoggen landjaeger, ball tip kielbasa prosciutto boudin tri-tip sirloin ribeye. Jowl buffalo pork belly sirloin cow porchetta. Salami prosciutto chuck doner swine buffalo beef andouille hamburger flank turkey short loin pork chop. Leberkas boudin ribeye chicken. Ball tip pancetta pork loin hamburger flank corned beef tongue meatloaf alcatra doner t-bone biltong buffalo rump. Sausage shankle beef beef ribs. T-bone ham hock rump venison swine sausage.</p>



Thank you in advance for any help.

Add a bottom padding. It won't affect the layout since you are dealing with an inline element


a {
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(#000 0 0) left bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: 0 1px;
  
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-size: 100% 1px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
<p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet picanha pork leberkas tail pig capicola. Fatback bacon rump biltong pastrami meatball cow. Meatloaf venison doner, flank swine pig beef bresaola corned beef capicola tri-tip bacon. Tri-tip rump ham short loin. Prosciutto porchetta corned beef rump. Pork chislic tri-tip short loin landjaeger andouille alcatra jerky sausage turkey. Chuck pastrami t-bone boudin doner pancetta pork chop flank pork shank spare ribs drumstick.</p>
<p>
<h3>Hover this link</h3>
  Andouille pork t-bone beef pig burgdoggen jowl. Shank short loin landjaeger rump alcatra pork belly jerky hamburger. <a href="">Pig cupim tongue meatball hamburger fatback flank prosciutto pork belly shank.</a>Chuck bresaola buffalo, short loin cow tongue tenderloin landjaeger beef cupim boudin shankle chislic t-bone. Sausage tenderloin hamburger leberkas kielbasa doner corned beef frankfurter tri-tip venison pastrami burgdoggen shankle. Kielbasa pancetta chicken strip steak. Cow bresaola biltong, boudin frankfurter filet mignon chislic andouille ham pork belly pastrami kevin.
</p>
<p>
  Biltong alcatra venison burgdoggen landjaeger, ball tip kielbasa prosciutto boudin tri-tip sirloin ribeye. Jowl buffalo pork belly sirloin cow porchetta. Salami prosciutto chuck doner swine buffalo beef andouille hamburger flank turkey short loin pork chop. Leberkas boudin ribeye chicken. Ball tip pancetta pork loin hamburger flank corned beef tongue meatloaf alcatra doner t-bone biltong buffalo rump. Sausage shankle beef beef ribs. T-bone ham hock rump venison swine sausage.</p>




So simple! Thank you so much.
